# passing longitude and latitude and distance as parameters in node js mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Hello I wrote this long mysql query that takes user longitude ,latitude and meters as input and shows the locations within 100 meters.
However I always get a mysql error near ? when I type `http://localhost:3002/closest/20.8877387/5.847748474/100`  in the browser. Could someone give me a hint?

```
 app.get('/closest/:lat/:lon/meters', (request, response) => {
        const lat = request.params.lat;
        const lon = request.params.lon;
        pool.query('SELECT *, ( ( ( Acos(Sin((  WHERE lat =? * Pi() / 180 )) * Sin((  map.lat* Pi() / 180 )) + Cos (( WHERE lat =? * Pi() / 180 )) * Cos(( map.lat* Pi() / 180 )) *  Cos  ((    (  WHERE lon = ? - map.lon ) * Pi() / 180 ))) ) *  180 / Pi  ()   ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * 1000 ) AS `METERS` FROM   base.map WHERE  "METERS" <= ?',lat,lon, (error, result) => {
            if (error) throw error;
     
            response.send(result);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Considering you state "mysql" in the Title, I'm going to assume this is not SQL Server related.

Comment: Have you tried running your query directly in a MySQL client program?

Comment: @O.Jones yes I get the same error message that there is a syntax error near ? , I think the `WHERE lat=?` is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't seem to  set the values of your `?` parameters. You need to provide them as an array as the second parameter to `.query(sqlStatement, parameterArray, callback)`. You have four `?`s in your query, so the array you provide must have four elements. `[lat, lat, lon, radius]` correspond to the purpose of your four `?`s. The `?` in your query represent conditional parameters.  You want
2. Your query says something like this.

```
SELECT bigFatFormula AS METERS FROM tbl WHERE METERS  < someDistance
```

That WHERE clause doesn't work. You have to say

```
SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT bigFatFormula AS METERS FROM tbl) result
  WHERE METERS < someDistance
```

In your query's WHERE clause, your `METERS` alias isn't in scope. The nested query puts it  in scope.

3. Your query contains a mess of nested WHERE clauses. That doesn't work.
4. Your get handler's first line needs to say this, with a colon on `meters`.

```
 app.get('/closest/:lat/:lon/:meters', (request, response) => {
```

So, you want something like this.

```
const lat = Number(request.params.lat);
const lon = Number(request.params.lon);
const radius = Number(request.params.meters);
var q = '
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, ( ( ( Acos(Sin(( ? * Pi() / 180 )) 
              * Sin((  map.lat* Pi() / 180 ))
              + Cos (( lat =? * Pi() / 180 )) *
                Cos(( map.lat* Pi() / 180 )) *
                Cos  (((   ? - map.lon ) * Pi() / 180 ))) )
               * 180 / Pi  ()   ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * 1000 ) 
                    AS METERS 
           FROM   base.map
    ) resultset WHERE METERS <= ?';

pool.query(q, [lat, lat, lon, radius], (error, result) => {
```

I haven't debugged this.

**Pro tip**: Your query will be very slow if you have lots of rows in your table. [Read this](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) for a suggestion.

**Pro tip**: You might want to use a stored function for your lat/lng - to - distance function, to make your query easier to read for the next person. Here's a [stable function](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/vicenty-great-circle-distance-formula/).

**Pro tip**:  It's often a good idea to debug complex queries like this using a SQL client program before trying to embed them into programs.

Comment: thank you :) I get no errors when excecuting the querry but I only get a blank page when i type localhost with it's parameters in the browser